# Newly added music not syncing to my iPhone after getting a new Mac (10.14.6 macOS Mojave), but iTunes library is identical

Tags: iphone, itunes, music

I replaced my old Mac Pro 1.1 tower with a newer 5.1 tower (running 10.14.6 macOS Mojave). I have a secondary drive that I hold multimedia on, including my music library. I removed this drive from my old Mac Pro and installed it in my new MP. Looking in iTunes the library looks identical as to when it was living on my old MP.

I added a few new albums today, but they did not get synced to my iPhone. How can I fix this? I do not want to switch to "manual" mode for syncing music to my iPhone, I just want the sync to update the music on my phone properly as it should.

Comment: Also, I saw this problem when I getting a new iMac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to force a new/fresh sync from the Mac to the iPhone to fix this. Not ideal, but it is what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try making a Playlist on your phone? I've read somewhere that this forces it to refresh, you can then delete it after.

Also you said you changed the drive, can you try de-authorizing and re-authorizing your new Mac ?